# Not Able To Install Apache Cordova for Windows Phone7

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, cordova

I am Trying To create an Application with Apache Cordova(Phonegap) For windows phone7.I followed the link[Apache Cordova For phone7](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/guide_getting-started_windows-phone_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Windows%20Phone) and the problem is am not able to find CordovaStarter-x.x.x.zip file in the downloaded content as mentioned in the instruction,[Download Link](http://phonegap.com/download).Plz sort out my problem.Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, VS templates is not bundled with phonegap 2.1.
In order to 'install' a template, you will need to build the template.
Simply open templates\full\CordovaSolution.sln in Visual Studio and from the file menu, choose 'Export Template'.

You can also test the sample solution located here \lib\windows-phone\example.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem as above  and I have found some solution.
Using  Visual studio 2010 and WindowsPhone 7.x  SDK   we create Phongegap app in Windows 7  and its  done by using template in visual studio 2010. 
 **Steps for Create Project in visual studio 2010:**

- Fist Download WindowsPhoneSDK7 for windows 7  [Microsoft Download Center](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=27570/)
- After that download  latest version of [Phonegap SDK](http://phonegap.com/download)
- open lib/Windows Phone folder after extracting  downloaded Phpnegap sdk
- In this folder  click on "createTemplates.bat"  file which generate zip file like **CordovaWP7_x_x_x.zip**
- Copy **CordovaWP7_x_x_x.zip** & Paste to  **Visual Studio 2010\Templates\ProjectTemplates\Visual C#**
- Now open Visual studio 2010 &  Start new project wich shows  **CordovaWP7_x_x_x.zip** Template then project created successfully.