# PhoneGap for Windows Phone - There is no script engine for file extension ".js"

Tags: visual-studio-2010, cordova

I've created new project using Microsoft visual Studio ,but got a compilation error as below:

1. There is no script engine for file extension ".js"
2. The command "CScript "c:\users\raja\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\EasyMed.3\EasyMed.3/BuildManifestProcessor.js" "c:\users\raja\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\EasyMed.3\EasyMed.3\EasyMed.3.csproj"" exited with code 1.

Any idea?

Comment: what is the solution for this problem..

Comment: Which version of PhoneGap? What instructions were you following?

Comment: Phonegap 2.1.0
I followed these instructions only--- http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/guide_getting-started_windows-phone_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Windows%20Phone

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This problem happens when your .js files become associated with something besides CScript.  Usually it happens when you decide to make some text editor the default.  You can reset it by typing this from a command line:

`assoc .js=JSFILE`

Comment: So now I have to lose my very useful IDE association just to run my simple script?  Typical (and ridiculous).

Comment: Yeah, it's not ideal that Visual Studio would require this.  Perhaps there's a VS specific setting that could get around it.  My solution would be to use the right-click edit for editing and let double-click be associated with execute.  You can modify this at `[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\<file_extension>`

Comment: Just right-click on your script, Open With, and go browse for your favorite text editor. It crazy to double-click on a script (an executable) file to edit the thing, anyway.

Comment: OMG, Thanks a million. For other users consider opening the CMD with administrative privilege

Answer (score 1):

The instructions for installing Cordova 2.1 for Windows Phone are not complete.

They say:

> - copy the file CordovaStarter-x.x.x.zip to the folder : \My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Templates\ProjectTemplates\

But that file is not supplied. There are updated instructions [here](https://github.com/purplecabbage/incubator-cordova-docs/blob/22cdc5a1bf43cd4015221558804ba2a809aab40a/docs/en/2.1.0/guide/getting-started/windows-phone/index.md) (see section 2.1).

Here is the issue at apache: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-1531

See also this question for more details: [Not Able To Install Apache Cordova for Windows Phone7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12759284/not-able-to-install-apache-cordova-for-windows-phone7)

Answer (score 1):

There is no script engine for file extension-----
Try this :

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=47809025-D896-482E-A0D6-524E7E844D81&displaylang=en