# PhoneGap for Android - There is no script engine for file extension “.js”

Tags: android, cordova

I'm using Windows 7 32-bit

I already installed all the required components and tested that following in cmd which are all working:
Ant
Java
Javac
Adb
Android

BUt when I try to create the project it says

> There is no script engine for file extension “.js”

```
create C:\Users\user05\workspace\mobileApp com.mobileApp mobileApp
```

UPDATE:
Ok I finally solved the issues. The problem is that the js file on my computer is associated with notepad++, so for some reason it is causing some conflict with it.

I used this fix to solve the issue: [link](http://www.winhelponline.com/articles/230/1/Error-There-is-no-script-engine-for-file-extension-when-running-js-files.html)!

Comment: Can you please tell me, how did you solve this issue? because me too getting same issue & i tried `assoc .j=JSFILE` command too..but create not working for me, it throwing `Input Error: There is no script engine for file extension ".js"`.

Answer (score 3):

Reset by typing into the command line:

```
assoc .js=JSFILE
```

this information was found here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13446640/2358237

Comment: Already tried that but i didn't work. Anyway I solved the issues already, thanks.

Comment: @AllanLopez: Can you please tell me, how did you solve this issue? because me too getting same issue & i tried `assoc .j=JSFILE` command too..but `create` not working for me, it throwing `Input Error: There is no script engine for file extension ".js".`

Comment: @AllanLopez curse you for not providing your solution

Comment: @Moak: Please check the update on how I solved my issue.