# Phonegap Install for Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, cordova, windows-phone-7.1

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Not Able To Install Apache Cordova for Windows Phone7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12759284/not-able-to-install-apache-cordova-for-windows-phone7)

Im trying to install Phonegap for visual studio 2010.

I downloaded the skd and installed it. from this link
[Windows Phone SDK](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/guide_getting-started_windows-phone_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Windows%20Phone)

I downloaded the phonegap zip here http://phonegap.com/download

the next step says to "•copy the file CordovaStarter-x.x.x.zip to the folder : \My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Templates\ProjectTemplates\"

The file i downloaded and extracted is phonegap-phonegap-2.1.0-0-g26d211b.zip.
I could not find any other zip file in all the directorys in that folder.

What am i missing or doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read furhter on and saw that i needed to do this step to get that template installed.

2.1. Building the template :
( note, this step may not be required. If the lib\windows-phone directory already contains a file CordovaStarter-x.x.x.zip then you may skip this step ) - Open the file lib\windows-phone\templates\standalone\CordovaSolution.sln in Visual Studio Express for Windows Phone - From the file menu, select 'Export Template...' - Choose template type 'Project template' - Give the exported template a name, ex. CordovaStarter-2.1.0 will produce CordovaStarter-2.1.0.zip - Optionally, you may add a description, icon image, and Preview image. These are what is displayed in Visual Studio in the 'New Project' dialog.- - Note: If you select ( 'Automatically import the template ... ') then you will not need to copy the .zip file over as outlined in step 2. - Press 'Finish'

Answer (score 1):

It says you should download Cordova too.

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/guide_getting-started_windows-phone_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Windows%20Phone

Comment: I followed that link and it leads to the phone gap download not cordova. I did download that phonegap zip already.